# Is there a way to kill tasks created by the compute function?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I know that the [`compute` function](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html) is based on the [`Isolate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html) API. For Isolate, you can request lsolate to shut down by calling the `kill` method of the islate object.

Can the `compute` function manually close Isolate running this task?

Comment: no, you cannot do that using `compute()` top level function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No

It is not possible to kill a [`compute` function](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html).

### Why

The reason for this is that looking at [the source code of the `compute` function](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/722b4277ca10a9475cb9fd5a3e0ea3097e0023b3/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart#L14), the created `isolate` is only killed after the `result` completer has finished:

```dart
final Completer<R> result = Completer<R>();
...
await result.future;
...
isolate.kill(); // Always awaits the result.
```

The result is only completed if there is either an error or the function you pass to `compute` returns.

---

Furthermore, you do **not** have *access to the `isolate`* **yourself** because it is [created inside of the `compute` function](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/722b4277ca10a9475cb9fd5a3e0ea3097e0023b3/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart#L21).

### Solution

If you want to be able kill the isolate you launch, do not use `compute`. Instead, you will have to create the `Isolate` yourself.